# Backtrace to shared library without using third party application

Tags: c, linux, backtrace

How can I get the function name and cause of the crash from shared library.
I have full access to shared library; I can recompile it with different flags, and even the main source too. Please let me know how to do it?

Currently I implemented backtrace functionality inside a signal handler but it is giving the trace of the main function but not the shared library trace.

Comment: Look up "core dump" and "gdb".

Comment: ...and don't forget to compile with debug symbols, else your trace will contain only memory addresses.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are using glibc, you can LD_PRELOAD the included libSegFault library to catch the signal and print the stack trace.

```
$ LD_PRELOAD=/lib/libSegFault.so ./a.out
```

Answer (score 0):

When you recompile the library use the -g flag.  Usually this is done with something like CFLAGS or CPPFLAGS in the Makefile.  In addition before you run gdb on your binary you should set the LD_LIBRARY_PATH to include the path to your debug version of the shared library (make sure your entry is at the front if other items exist in LD_LIBRARY_PATH).  Finally you can copy the source into the working directory so that the source code can be found and you can set break points.